# Change buttons on fancybox button helper if one image

Tags: jquery, fancybox

Edit: Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1f5uqgb9/16/). I'm trying to get the second image (bird) to only show Toggle and Close on the button helper since it only has one image in the gallery.

I'm trying to remove the Prev, Play and Forward buttons on the button helper if there is only one image.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.fancybox-buttons').fancybox({
        helpers: {
            buttons: {
                if (this.group.length == 1) {
                    tpl: '<div id="fancybox-buttons"><ul style="width:74px"><li><a class="btnToggle" title="Toggle size" href="javascript:;"></a></li><li><a class="btnClose" title="Close" href="javascript:;"></a></li></ul></div>',
                } else {
                    tpl: '<div id="fancybox-buttons"><ul><li><a class="btnPrev" title="Previous"></a></li><li><a class="btnPlay" title="Start slideshow"></a></li><li><a class="btnNext" title="Next"></a></li><li><a class="btnToggle" title="Toggle size"></a></li><li><a class="btnClose" title="Close"></a></li></ul></div>',
                }
            },
        },
    });
});
```

Clearly I have no idea what I am doing. This gives me a "SyntaxError: missing formal parameter" on the 'if (this.group.length == 1)' line. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: You are going to have to show some more of your code (relevant HTML). Is `.fancy-buttons` the class name you are using for the fancybox wrapper div?

Comment: My html is <div><a class="fancybox-buttons" rel="Image1" href="image1.jpg"><img src="image1.jpg" alt="" /></a></div>.  The button helper jquery.fancybox-buttons.js usage shows what I have but without if statements. I get the "tpl" I want without the if statements, I'm just trying to add a condition. Sorry, I realize I'm in over my head.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax error is caused by the if...else conditional statement, they cannot exist inside of an object in that way.

You could try something like this though:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var fancyTpl = $('.fancybox-buttons').length === 1
        ? '<div id="fancybox-buttons"><ul style="width:74px"><li><a class="btnToggle" title="Toggle size" href="javascript:;"></a></li><li><a class="btnClose" title="Close" href="javascript:;"></a></li></ul></div>'
        : '<div id="fancybox-buttons"><ul><li><a class="btnPrev" title="Previous"></a></li><li><a class="btnPlay" title="Start slideshow"></a></li><li><a class="btnNext" title="Next"></a></li><li><a class="btnToggle" title="Toggle size"></a></li><li><a class="btnClose" title="Close"></a></li></ul></div>';

    $('.fancybox-buttons').fancybox({
        helpers: {
            buttons: {
                tpl: fancyTpl
            },
        },
    });
});
```

---

This is not tested, however the buttons may be disabled automatically for 1 image if you add the optional `loop` argument set to false like:

```
$('.fancybox-buttons').fancybox({
    loop: false,
});
```

[Reference to fancyBox options](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#docs)

Comment: Thanks. This is better. I'm not getting errors now.  It will only set the variable to whatever I have for the second one : even if there is only one image. I'll go educate myself some more on your code and update later.

Comment: I see clearer now.  It needs to evaluate the length by the total like 'rel' attributes. It's getting the amount by how many images I have with the same class instead. I think maybe I need to do something with fancybox's afterLoad or beforeShow but I'm just not sure how to update the 'tpl' from there. Back at it..

Comment: I couldn't get anywhere with removing the buttons on a condition.  The loop: false at least disables them so I went with that. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score -1):

If I could see the whole document maybe I can help you more. But maybe the problem is .length. try .length() or .length() <= 1 or combinations :)

Comment: That is still going to be invalid syntax. You cannot have conditional statements mixed within an object like that.